# How to use OR operator in Regular Expression

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I am validating a textbox in MVC3 razor using Data Annotation. I want to match two different conditions for a textbox. How should I display two different error messages depending upon the condition?

Here is my sample code:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^PR[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ | ^PR[a-zA-Z0-9]2([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Product | Invalid ITN")]
```

I want to display separate error messages for the conditions:

- `^PR[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`
- `^PR[a-zA-Z0-9]2([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$`

Comment: May be it is better to use two regular expressions for each message and validation rule?

Comment: You want to show one error message on `^PR[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` and a different one on `^PR[a-zA-Z0-9]2([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you cannot display different messages, for one regex, you should  use two regular expressions for each message and validation rule take a look on [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)